# What is the fastest way to download videos off my Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I have a web based platform that offers a directory of all the videos on my azure storage for download. At the moment I am using blob.download but it is so slow it is downloading at about 5Mbps. I was hoping some one could help me speed this up. I know it is possible since the azure storage explorer can transfer the videos onto my local machine 10x as fast

This is my current python code:

```
with open(file_downloaded, "wb") as my_blob:
  blob_data = blob.download_blob()
  blob_data.readinto(my_blob)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try using the AzCopy tool to download blobs from Azure Blob Storage**. AzCopy is a command-line utility that you can use to copy data to and from Azure Blob Storage. It is designed to be fast and efficient, and **it can transfer data at speeds of up to 10 Gbps.**

Here is an example of how to download a blob using AzCopy in Python

```py
import os
import subprocess

def download_blob_with_azcopy(account_name, account_key, container_name, blob_name, local_path):
    azcopy_path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\AzCopy\\azcopy.exe"
    source_blob_url = f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}"
    destination_path = os.path.abspath(local_path)
    command = f"{azcopy_path} cp \"{source_blob_url}\" \"{destination_path}\" --recursive --quiet --from-to BlobLocal"
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)

# Example usage
download_blob_with_azcopy("myaccount", "mykey", "mycontainer", "myblob", "C:\\temp\\myblob")
```

You will need to replace the `account_name`, `account_key`, `container_name`, `blob_name`, and `local_path` parameters with the appropriate values for your blob.

Thanks to @[Otávio Simões Silveira](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-subprocess/) for  python subprocess blog.

For Sample purpose created blobs in azure storage account and then by following this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-download) copy/downloaded blobcontent using Azcopy in azure portal commandshell as shown in below image.
[image]
The syntax for azcpoy here i followed is  is **azcopy copy "sourceurl" "destinationurl" --recursive**
Here you can see the time, success and failure transfer of blob details.

- you can also try  **content delivery network (CDN)** to disperse blob operations, such [Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-a-storage-account-with-cdn). A globally dispersed network of computers called Azure CDN can cache and transport material from Azure Blob Storage to users all over the world, **lowering latency and enhancing download speeds**. Create a CDN endpoint and set it up to utilise your Blob Storage account as the origin if you want to use Azure CDN with Blob Storage. So, rather than using the Blob Storage URL, you may access your content using the CDN endpoint URL.